# Loading project definition, server access Error

Tags: playframework

I'm creating my first app. After running the build script, you use the Play console with the Play command:

```
[me@c0006462 myFirstApp]$ play
[info] Loading project definition from /home/me/play-2.1.3/myFirstApp/project
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.parboiled/parboiled-core/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml

[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.parboiled/parboiled-core/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml

...
```

And then it spits out a list of other URLs that are 404s. I don't know where these URLs are coming from or how to fix them.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a proxy issue.
if you are on windows.
update sbt.bat the java_opts with proxy information.
set _JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyHost=... -Dhttp.proxyPort=..